# Unknown space between links

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

I have three links:

```
<a href="/about" class="f_link">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;About&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a>
<a href="/Login" class="f_link">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Login&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a>
<a href="/Create Account" class="f_link">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Create Account&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a>
```

I have some CSS styling for them:

```
.f_link{
height:38px;
padding-top:12px;
margin:0px;
color:gray;
}
.f_link:hover{
color:black;
text-decoration:none;
}
```

How this html is displayed in FF 3.6, IE 8, and some version of Google Chrome:
[image]

And this is how I would like it to be displayed in my three major browers:
[image]

I used firebug and it said there is no padding or margin between these links. What is that space there for then, and how can I get rid of it? I'm open to suggestions!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Line breaks are/should be treated as a single white space in HTML. You can update your markup to this (line break before the closing tag, but no space before the next A tag)

```
<a href="/about" class="f_link">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;About&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
</a><a href="/Login" class="f_link">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Login&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
</a><a href="/Create Account" class="f_link">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Create Account&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a>
```

Answer (score 4):

Add `float: left;` to your `.f_link` declaration, that will remove spaces.

http://jsfiddle.net/wMwEQ/

Also, using `&nbsp;` for spacing is baaaad, even though it's not an issue here.

Comment: This works fine but I didn't want my links to go to the left or right of the containing element, so I would have to use a div wrapping those links and then center that div @naivists had a solution that was nice and easy. Thanks for your help though.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to slightly change your layout to get the results you're looking for...plus this:

```
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;About&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
```

Is really unnecessary.

```
HTML:
<ul class="my_list">
    <li><a href="#">My Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">My Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">My Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">My Link</a></li>
</ul>

CSS:
.my_list { overflow:hidden; } // Clear floats
.my_list li { float:left; list-style:none; margin:0; padding:0; }
.my_list li a { padding:0 10px; }
```

That should do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

The space is the spaces between the `</a>` closing tag and the following `<a>` opening tag. Remove that space in your markup and you should have the desired effect.

Answer (score 0):

One solution to this problem is also to include all the links in a div and set the div's `font-size:0;`  then set the font-size of the links as you wish.

You can check the fiddle below for more info

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RnupZ/)