# Force empty space betweek two links?

Tags: html, css

I've noticed that if I have two links  :

```
<a href="#">Text</a>
<a href="#">Text</a>
```

[They](http://jsfiddle.net/eAteH/) are not joined in the browser, looks like there is a space between them.

But if I [wrote](http://jsfiddle.net/eAteH/1/) them in one line :

```
<a href="#">Text</a><a href="#">Text</a>
```

there is no space. Is there a way to delete that space? Or I need to write all links (or better, all inline elements) in one line?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5147258/unknown-space-between-links

Comment: @dennisg in that duplicate answer he have to change his markup manually .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **word-spacing** write like this:

```
a
{
    display:inline;
    background-color:red;
    word-spacing:1em
}
body{word-spacing:-1em}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/eAteH/2/

There other way also like **font-size:0** check this [Strange margin on `display:inline-block`-elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9664321/strange-margin-on-displayinline-block-elements)

Comment: uhm yeah, but I don't like put font-size:0 on body : this means I need to set it on all elements...

Comment: as dennisg said you can define to anchor parent element. Like this http://jsfiddle.net/eAteH/5/