# 1px space between <a> tag in firefox

Tags: html, css, spacing

I have used `font-size: 0;` on the parent element and that's how I got the links to have no spaces but the space is still there in Firefox.

Please test this in Firefox and then any other browser and you'll see that Firefox is showing a space (*albeit 1px*) between the links where as no other browser is doing this... well IE6&7 but lets not talk about them...

http://jsfiddle.net/uZMzA/

Does anyone know why? And how I could go about and solving it without using javascript to determine the browser?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unknown space between links](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5147258/unknown-space-between-links)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why this is happening is because there is a text-node with a line-break in between the a-tags. And since you have set `letter-spacing: 1px;` and the firefox coders have chosen to implement letter-spacing the way they have, you get 1px of letter spacing after or before that textnode.

The solution, as already hinted at elsewhere, is to change the rule for `div#navigation` to not have the line `letter-spacing: 1px` in it, like this:

```
div#navigation {
  position: relative;
  padding: 1px 0;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  font-family: Georgia, Serif;
  margin: 0 auto 2px auto;
  width: 400px;
  font-size: 0;
  text-shadow: 0 1px #fff;
}
```

You can see a working version with the fix applied here: http://jsfiddle.net/uZMzA/10/

Answer (score 1):

maybe you mean:

```
letter-spacing: 0
```

This cause your *"bug"*

---

Edit:

If you want the letter spacing at 1px, this is a good solution, [fiddle up](http://jsfiddle.net/uZMzA/12/)

Just adding:

`display: inline-block` to the `Div` container css and `float: left` to the `a` element.

Answer (score 1):

Read this post. You will find all available techniques on its body and comments, as well as their tradeoffs.

http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

The "remove the spaces" option is mentioned first, as it's the easiest to implement. But it's also "a bit funky".

The "letter-spacing - based" option is listed in the comments, but notice that you will have to include additional css if you want to make IE < 8 happy.

Comment: I knew I read something about this just the other day. Good link.

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove the white  space from your code like this **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/uZMzA/1/)**.

HTML:

```
<div id="navigation">
    <a href="#">Link1</a><a href="#">Link2</a><a href="#">Link3</a><a href="#">Link4</a>
</div>​
```

Comment: Why the downvote? I don't know why was stupid enough to downvote multiple answers here but this is the right solution.

Comment: -1 because it is not really a solution. You let the layout be dictated by the sourcecode, which you should never do. The correct solution is to remove the rule `letter-spacing: 1px` which is causing the problem.

Comment: It is absolutely a solution since the OP's problem is caused by white space that either commenting or removing will fix.

Comment: The problem is not the sourcecode but the style being applied. Changing the source code is a solution the same way taking pain pills is the solution to the headache you get by repeatedly headbutting a  wall. But the real solution for that is of cause to stop headbutting the wall.

Answer (score 0):

This is silly and I can't really explain the "why" of that occurrence but here are two ways to correct the display.

FF doesn't like the space in the code.  Either remove the carriage returns between your `<a>` tags or comment them out, like this:

```
<div id="navigation">
    <a href="#">Link1</a><!--
    --><a href="#">Link2</a><!--
    --><a href="#">Link3</a><!--
    --><a href="#">Link4</a>
</div>
```